# How do I stop a Bootstrap carousel from hijacking the fragment identifier (#...) in the URL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-5

I have a full screen carousel at the top of my web page using Bootstrap 5. It works great. Whenever I navigate to the web page, though, it changes the fragment identifier (i.e. http://url.com#carousel-section) to the first slide on the carousel.

The truth is that I have a tab control on the page, and I am trying to utilize sticky tabs so that when I navigate to, say, http://url.com#tab-1, it opens up the tab with ID of tab-1. Whenever I navigate to the URL with the fragment identifier of the tab pane, Bootstrap takes over and changes the fragment identifier before sticky tabs can move the tab control into the viewport.

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve the following: When I navigate to the URL with a fragment identifier, if the ID matches a tab panel, go to it; otherwise, go to the carousel.

Comment: Simple answer: don't use `#tab-1`, use something else, eg `?tab=tab-1`

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks. I have implemented your suggestion, and it works well.